# runtime creation of functions in phpunit

Tags: phpunit

Is there any way of creating testcases runtime by giving paramters?
Functionality of the test cases is same, just name and parameters will differ.

Like here is an example

```
public function testGetGiftsGivenVideo() {
        $fileName = 'get-gifts-given-video.json';
        $filePath = $this->path . $fileName;
        $this->accessToken = $this->coreAPI->GetOAuthToken($this->loginFilePath);
        $this->compareResults($filePath, $this->accessToken, true);
    }

    public function testGetGiftsReceivedAudio() {
        $fileName = 'get-gifts-received-audio.json';
        $filePath = $this->path . $fileName;
        $this->accessToken = $this->coreAPI->GetOAuthToken($this->loginFilePath);
        $this->compareResults($filePath, $this->accessToken, true);
    }

    public function testGetGiftsReceivedVideo() {
        $fileName = 'get-gifts-received-video.json';
        $filePath = $this->path . $fileName;
        $this->accessToken = $this->coreAPI->GetOAuthToken($this->loginFilePath);
        $this->compareResults($filePath, $this->accessToken, true);
    }
```

Now all these functions are doing the same thing.

Comment: Where is the difference between those methods? Or did you forgot to change the value of `$fileName`?

Comment: O yes. Thanks for the correction.
I just edited the post.
Yes, the difference lies in just $filename.

Comment: I've a number of test cases like this, just $filename differs. Is there any way to avoid this duplication of code?

Comment: It looks like a good candidate for [data providers](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html#writing-tests-for-phpunit.data-providers).

Comment: I thought about that, too, yes

Comment: But is it possible to change the function name each time?

Comment: Yes, thats the second solution I thought about. I'll write an answer for that

Comment: O great. Thanks. I am waiting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two possible solutions here:

As suggested by axiac in the comments, you can use data providers.

A data provider is a method returning an array of parameters to call a test method multiple times with different parameters. See the [PHPUnit documentation about data providers](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html#writing-tests-for-phpunit.data-providers) for more information

```
/**
 * @dataProvider provideGetGifts
 * @param $filename
 */
public function testGetGifts($fileName) {
    $filePath = $this->path . $fileName;
    $this->accessToken = $this->coreAPI->GetOAuthToken($this->loginFilePath);
    $this->compareResults($filePath, $this->accessToken, true);
}


public function provideGetGifts()
{
    return array(
        array('get-gifts-given-video.json'),
        array('get-gifts-received-audio.json'),
        array('get-gifts-received-video.json'),
    );
}
```

The second solution, if you want to have different method names, is to simply use a second method which includes some logic of the test:

```
protected function compareAccessTokenWithFilePath($fileName) {
    $filePath = $this->path . $fileName;
    $this->accessToken = $this->coreAPI->GetOAuthToken($this->loginFilePath);
    $this->compareResults($filePath, $this->accessToken, true);
}

public function testGetGiftsGivenVideo() {
    $this->compareAccessTokenWithFilePath('get-gifts-given-video.json');
}

public function testGetGiftsReceivedAudio() {
    $this->compareAccessTokenWithFilePath('get-gifts-given-audio.json');
}

public function testGetGiftsReceivedVideo() {
    $this->compareAccessTokenWithFilePath('get-gifts-received-video.json');
}
```

Personally, I'd prefer the first solution. Its a little bit clearer.

Comment: Yeah, I thought about the second solution but it does not seem so good. For time, I will use first solution. Thanks.